# Postgresql: set default psql client encoding

Tags: postgresql, configuration, psql, encoding

When I connect to a Postgresql DB using `psql`, I often get these messages:

```
=> SELECT * FROM question_view ;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd7 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
```

Following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525505/postgres-issue-encoding-utf8-has-no-equivalent-in-encoding-latin1), I understand that I should change the client encoding accordingly:

```
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
```

Changing the `client_encoding` every time I connect to the DB is cumbersome. Is there a way to permanently configure this setting, either in the `.pgpass` file or anywhere else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *Is there a way to permanently configure this setting, either in the .pgpass file or anywhere else*

Yes there is: it's `~/.psqlrc` (or `%APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf` in Windows)

See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88713

Comment: Adding `SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';` to `~/.psqlrc` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when (re)connecting from within a `psql` session, for example after restarting the server.

Comment: I had to create this file in Windows and then set a user environment var called PSQLRC pointing to that directory. No more complaints, yay

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error but changing from ANSI(X64) to Unicode(x64) in my ODBC conn fixed my issue.